# ERROR USER_PROJECT_DENIED while executing pubsub function in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloudcustodian

I have PubSub function in GCP , which is running rules of cloud custodian and have notify functionality for sending mail i.e. c7n mailer and call c7n_mailer pubsub function.
Now, I am running this function against all project from one project.

I have checked and provide all permission, cloudcustodian successfully run against project ,, but when it comes to notify and run against c7n_mailer pubsub, its giving me below permission issue.

I have provided permission by adding role of pubsub list / get etc in xxx project but still getting issue.

`Invalid JSON content from response: b'{\n "error": {\n "code": 403,\n "message": "Caller does not have required permission to use project xxx. Grant the caller the Owner or Editor role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting https://console.xxx.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=xxx and then retry (propagation of new permission may take a few minutes).",\n "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n "details": [\n {\n "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",\n "links": [\n {\n "description": "Google developer console IAM admin",\n "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=xxx"\n }\n ]\n },\n {\n "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n "reason": "USER_PROJECT_DENIED",\n "domain": "googleapis.com",\n "metadata": {\n "service": "pubsub.googleapis.com",\n "consumer": "projects/xxx"\n }\n }\n ]\n }\n}\n'`

Comment: Edit your question and include your code and details on what it is doing. The identity that you are using does not have **serviceusage.services.use** on all projects. Typically, if you need to perform tasks for all projects, then the permission is granted at the ORG or Folder level.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and Google's error would both benefit from more detail.

However, what is clear from the 403 from the Google service is that you've granted insufficient permissions to the Service Account on project XXX:

`Caller does not have required permission to use project xxx`

It's difficult to answer the question without knowing what exactly the account needs to do on project XXX but, if you're only accessing PubSub in the project, I'd recommend bumping the PubSub role and trying again:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles